# How to populate/intialize a list in a stateless widget using a provider. without calling the method

Tags: flutter

I am using Provider and a stateless widget, I will like to populate the _allContacts list without calling the getAllContacts in my stateless widget, like i will call the getAllContacts in initState if I was using stateful widget

```
class ContactModel with ChangeNotifier{



List<Contact> _allContacts;

get contacts => this._allContacts;

getAllContacts() async{
  if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {

     _allContacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();

     print(_allContacts.toList());
   }

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ContactModel with ChangeNotifier{
  
  ContactModel(){
    _getAllContacts();
  }

  List<Contact> _allContacts;

  get contacts => this._allContacts;

  _getAllContacts() async{
    if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {

      _allContacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();

      print(_allContacts.toList());
    }
    notifyListeners();

  }

}
```